# Animating Header on scroll, firing too many times

Tags: jquery

how can I stop these css and animate functions running more than once when the user scrolls? Currently they fire for every pixel the user scrolls, this is causing problems!

```
<script>
  var elementPosition = $('#main-wrap').offset();
  var x = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top && x != 0){
      $('#dropdown-navwrap .dropdown-bar').animate({ width: "80%", overflow: "visible" }, 400);
      $('#header').animate({ top: "44px" }, 400, function() { $(this).animate("padding", "0"); });

      $('#hdr-logo').animate({ opacity: "0" }, 400, function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
      $("#hdr-social").animate({ opacity: "0" }, 400, function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
      $(".contact-box").animate({ opacity: "0" }, 400, function() {
        $(this).css("display", "none"); ($('#header').css("height", "30px")).css("padding", "0px");
        // logo
        ($('#sticky-contact').css("display", "block")).animate({opacity: 1.0});
        $("a[href*=logo-sticky]").animate({opacity: 1.0});
      });
    } else {
      $('#dropdown-navwrap .dropdown-bar').animate({ width: "100%", overflow: "visible" }, 400);

      $('#hdr-logo').animate({ opacity: "1" }, 400, function() { $(this).css("display", "visible"); });
      $("#hdr-social").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 400, function() { $(this).css("display", "visible"); });
      $(".contact-box").animate({ opacity: "1" }, 400, function() {
        $(this).css("display", "visible"); ($('#header').css("height", "95px")).css("padding", "15px 0");
        // logo
        ($('#sticky-contact').animate({opacity: 0})).css("display", "none");
        $("a[href*=logo-sticky]").animate({opacity: 0});
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) in your case.

Comment: I cant be installing any additional libraries :/

Comment: Then you can set a var that changes to true/false every first time you change the scroll direction and prevent your function to fire every time. Just an idea.

Comment: @GerardCuadras, I thought about that, but think im doing it wrong! Could you show me a quick example ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
<script>
var elementPosition = $('#main-wrap').offset();
var x = 0;
var top = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top && x != 0) {
        if (top == false) {
            $('#dropdown-navwrap .dropdown-bar').animate({width: "80%", overflow: "visible"}, 400);
            $('#header').animate({top: "44px"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).animate("padding", "0");
            });

            $('#hdr-logo').animate({opacity: "0"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
            $("#hdr-social").animate({opacity: "0"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
            $(".contact-box").animate({opacity: "0"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
                $('#header').css("height", "30px").css("padding", "0px");
                $('#sticky-contact').css("display", "block").animate({opacity: 1.0});
                $("a[href*=logo-sticky]").animate({opacity: 1.0});
            });
            top = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (top == true) {
            $('#dropdown-navwrap .dropdown-bar').animate({width: "100%", overflow: "visible"}, 400);

            $('#hdr-logo').animate({opacity: "1"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "visible");
            });
            $("#hdr-social").animate({opacity: "1"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "visible");
            });
            $(".contact-box").animate({opacity: "1"}, 400, function () {
                $(this).css("display", "visible");
                $('#header').css("height", "95px").css("padding", "15px 0");
                $('#sticky-contact').animate({opacity: 0}).css("display", "none");
                $("a[href*=logo-sticky]").animate({opacity: 0});
            });
            top = false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I can't test it because I don't have your HTML. But, the purpose is to prevent the function fires two times while scrolling down or scrolling top.

If we set the variable `top` to `false` the first time we will let the function to fire while scrolling down. Then, after fires we set to `true`, so if we continue scrolling down the function will not do anything. Will happen the same when scrolling top.